# On receiving a byte sequence for Unicode characters, how does python interpreter decide the encoding scheme to decode and get the code point(s)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am using python 2.7. My terminal's encoding scheme is set as 'UTF-8'. Python's default encoding scheme is 'ascii'.

```
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
```

I typed the following on python interactive shell

```
>>> x = u'à'
>>> x
u'\xe0'
```

It prints the Unicode codepoint for the character 'à'. The byte sequence received by the python interpretor would be:

```
x           space       =           space       u           quote       à - 1st byte    à - 2nd byte    quote

1111000     100000      111101      100000      1110101     100111      11000010        10100001        100111
```

Now how did the python interpretor decide what encoding scheme should it use to get the Unicode code point from byte sequence '11000010 10100001'? Did it use the setting sys.stdin.encoding?

```
>>> sys.stdin.encoding
'UTF-8'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Python detects the terminal encoding (if possible) and uses `sys.stdin.encoding` for terminal input and `sys.stdout.encoding` for terminal output.

In scripts, the bytes in the source code will be used, but Python needs to know the source encoding using a special comment.  So if the following is saved in UTF-8 as a script, you'll get the same result.

```
# coding: utf-8
x = u'à'
```